# Implementing messaging service in PHP-JavaScript

Tags: javascript, service, web, messaging

I have a intranet web database application in a LAMP environment. I would like to implement an internal messaging service like e-mail but just for the users in my application. I don't want any code just the general idea on how can something like this be implemented. I'm not very strong in JavaScript but I always learn whatever I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

1. make database table called messages. (id, body, time, author)
2. Make an HTML form with textarea and submit, action can be the same PHP page or other. (I prefare same page idea.)
3. once the form is submitted, sanitize data for database and create variable which will hold the text from the textarea.
4. insert this text in messages table.
5. then some JavaScript-PHP code which will display all the messages from the database below, next to or above the form.
   If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: Okay, that sounds pretty straight forward. But what I find difficult is a way to inform users that they have new messages. Like facebook notifications. I have done the css part for the notifications but how am I gonna check (and how often) if there are new messages?

Comment: It's really about how to do it on chatting page, sorry dude, but I have no idea how to inform users about new message :(

Comment: That's the problem, users do not visit the chat/messaging page unless they know they got new messages or they want to send a new message. I can't ask all users to check their messages every few minutes. Anyway, thanks for your time.